# Script Documents in Visual Studio 2012 for Firefox

Tags: asp.net, debugging, firefox, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I know how to debug scripts and aspx controls using Visual Studio and Internet Explorer (Script Documents). However in IE app works very well. On the other hand in Firefox (latest) I get many errors and one of them is:

```
Error message: InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character Address: http://localhost/myApp/Pages/Documents.aspx?FormId=158c8347-34fe-4547-a357-fd04174d1b23&ElId=9711 Line: 458
```

When I hit debug (F5) in VS2012 in IE, Script Documents are generated in solution, but if I set Firefox as browser Script Documents are missing. Is there any other way to see HTML?

Using view page source doesn't work — shown code has only 200 lines and some JS for async operations.

Comment: Have you tried Firebug?

Comment: Dynamically added HTML will not show up in view source like you said, so you need to use some type of developer tool like Firebug (Firefox), F12 tools (IE) or Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: I have Firebug and looked through DOM, but didn't find "raw" html source.

Comment: HTML tab, in between Console and CSS tabs.

Comment: I think HTML tab didn't show dynamic code. I'll verify that on Tuesday.